# C++ A-star implementation -- determining whether a node is already in the priority queue of open items

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, path-finding, a-star

One step in the A* pathfinding algorithm requires searching the list of open nodes for the node you're currently interacting with, and adding that node to the list if it isn't already there, or updating its value and parent, if it's present but with a higher weight than the current version of the node.

These behaviors aren't supported in the STL priority_queue structure. How should I implement that step?

**Updates** since this question is getting a lot of views:

- std::priority_queue may look like a good choice for this, but it isn't.
- Implementing A* yourself is an enormous confidence-booster, but after you've done it, you should try to switch to using the one provided by boost. I was nervous about installing it when I asked this question, but installation is very easy and won't produce any complications; and A* isn't the only useful functionality that boost provides. (In particular, if you don't use their string-processing functionality, you'll end up writing your own copy of it; I speak from personal experience...)

Comment: I wouldn't even do that anyway, unless space is at a premium. Is there any reason you can't/shouldn't maintain a separate set that support quick "contains" queries?

Comment: Could you clarify what it is that isn't necessary to do here? @ybungalobill, below, said that refreshing the node to the lowest-cost version was mandatory for optimal results.

Comment: It is, but finding the right node to change *in the priority queue* is a slow operation. You can maintain a separate data structure to handle that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a plain vector or array to store the elements and then use `std::make_heap`, `std::push_heap`, `std::pop_heap`, `std::sort_heap`, `std::is_heap` and `std::is_heap_until` to manage it.

This allows you to break containment and implement custom operations on a priority queue, without having to implement the standard operations yourself.

Comment: If I take this approach, how do I pass a different predicate function to make_heap()? It's refusing greater<SearchNode>, saying "type name is not allowed."

Comment: Update: looks like I just needed to declare an instance of greater<SearchNode>. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr: I added a code sample showing how to use `std::greater`.  My guess is you forgot to put brackets after it to indicate that you want to construct an anonymous temporary.

Answer (score 2):

STL `priority_queue` does not suit for A* implementation. You need a heap structure that supports the `increase` operation to change the priority of already inserted items. Use [Boost.Heap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/heap.html) for an implementation of many classical heaps.

**EDIT:** Boost.Graph library has [an implementation of A* search](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html) too.

Comment: Is it right to say that, if you find a version of a particular node with a lower total cost than the version you currently have in the queue, you must replace the version in the queue with the new, cheaper version? It sounds like it, but I want to be sure.

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr: yes, otherwise you won't get optimal solutions. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) algorithm pseudocode.

Comment: Thanks. But are there ways to get a suitable container without needing to install Boost?

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr: you can use a `multi_set` as @compileGuy suggested, or use the heap functions that @Andrew listed and implement `increase`/`decrease` for array-based heaps yourself. However, these approaches will result in O(log N) updates, while most of Boost's heaps have amortized O(1) updates.

Comment: ybungalobill: I'm currently doing pathfinding over a 24x13 world map, for relatively modest numbers of actors, so I think O(log N) is tolerable; but if I find myself integrating Boost into the project at some point in the future, this certainly be an area in which to use it.

Comment: isn't a priority queue on of the best ways to optimise A*

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke: "priority queue" is the best, but not "STL `priority_queue`" that I was talking about. The problem of the standard `priority_queue` is that... explained in the answer.

Comment: http://www.comp.dit.ie/bduggan/research/an%20optimised%20implementation%20of%20the%20a%20star%20algorithm%20using%20the%20stl.pdf read this paper :)

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke: Oh my god... It is a paper written by amateurs. What actually matters is not the paper (which does not explain anything) but the implementation. And the problem of the implementation is that it causes *undefined behavior* by invalidating the `priority_queue` invariants (that is by modifying the values directly without letting priority_queue to prearrange itself. see line 90 of PathFinder.cpp). Their "algorithm" is just broken, and they are lucky that they got correct results (if they checked correctness at all, which I doubt).

Comment: i agree; however I still think an STL priority queue can be used in this case (even if a heap structure is obviously a better implementation) and that's what I was trying to show you.

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke: If you "still think" so, then [*you* shall prove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot) that it is possible. My proof of impossibility is simple: A* modifies the priority values of the nodes in the priority queue, `priority_queue` does not support such modifications, therefore it is impossible to use `priority_queue` to implement `A*`.

Comment: okay; i doesn't support it (directly) no but you can make two priority_queues and just copy them to the other priority_queue when you have to change the fscore (or priority) for a node; http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577457-a-star-shortest-path-algorithm/ (Russell's teapot :p nice ref. ).

Comment: @ThomasVerbeke: but then (as in the code you linked) you break the time complexity of A*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are limited to STL you could use STL Set and constantly erasing and re-inserting the elements (with new priority).

```
Set< pair<int,int> > s; // < priority,value >
s.insert( make_pair(0,5) );

// Decrease Key operation //
s.erase( s.find( make_pair(0,5) ) );
s.insert( make_pair(1,5) );
```

Time complexity is still O(log N) but it will probably take more time for large sets.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I used for this if you really want to use std::priority_queue:

When you need to update a node that is already in the priority queue, just insert a new node having the same state and a new cost value and parent into the queue. The most recently updated copy of this node will come off the queue first and be added to your visited set. To deal with the older duplicates, check any node coming off the queue against your visited set before processing it. If it is in the visited set then the lowest-cost path through this node has already been seen, so just ignore it and process the next node.

Comment: This is probably the simplest approach and [avoids the bookkeeping overhead](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/ImplementationNotes.html#binary-heaps) associated with “mutable” priority queues.

Answer (score 0):

There are three likely solutions to this:

1. Track the list of nodes currently open independently of the priority queue. Try creating a list of nodes in the same manner you do for closed nodes.
2. Create a map of nodes (by coordinate) to open-closed state.
3. Install the Boost library, which includes a templated implementation of A* (I think in `<graph>`).